# Selenium : firefox webdriver keep former html code

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I created a python script with the selenium library for automating some actions. My script works with chromedriver whereas when I want to use the firefox driver it doesn't work as well. This is because after connecting my script to a website the driver does not update it to the html source code, so I grabbed the html code from the old page instead of the current html code. So my script can't find any items.

Do you have any idea why this error only appears with geckodriver and do you know how to fix it please?

Code bellow is the different between chromedriver and firefox driver :

```
     if const.browser == 'chrome':
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # Ouverture d'un onglet en dimension plein écran
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Modification du chemin de téléchargements
        prefs = {"download.default_directory" : const.download_path}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

        # Déclaration du driver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=const.chrome_driver_path, options=options)
    else:
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Optionnel
        # Ouverture d'un onglet en dimension plein écran
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        # options.add_argument("--headless")
        # Modification du chemin de téléchargements
        options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
        options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", const.download_path)

        # Déclaration du driver
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=const.firefox_driver_path, options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open Firefox driver instead of Chrome Driver.

```
driver = webdriver.FireFox(executable_path=const.firefox_driver_path, options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it was a code error. This does not solve the problem which continues and my driver keeps the old html code before action while under chrome no, however the firefox window is present on the correct view